# Set content page icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created an hamburguer menu with master detail page. In the detail page i would like to have a botton navigation bar with shortcuts (like twitter app for android) but icons of eash shortcuts are not being displayed.
I tried using url, file path and ImageSource but none of these displayed the image icon.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KiaiDay.Views.Main.HomePage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:KiaiDay.Views.Main"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiaiDay.MarkupExtensions" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">


  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
...

  </MasterDetailPage.Master>


    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:HomePageDetail />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Homepagedetail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="KiaiDay.Views.Main.HomePageDetail"
            Title="Pagina Inicial"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiaiDay.MarkupExtensions"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:view ="clr-namespace:KiaiDay.Views.PosLogin"
            BarBackgroundColor="LightGray" BarTextColor="White"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">

    <ContentPage Title="Home" Icon="{local:ImageResource KiaiDay.Images.calendarWhite.png}" NavigationPage.TitleIcon="calendarWhite.png"/>
    <ContentPage Icon="calendarWhite.png"/>
    <ContentPage Icon="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/calendar-11.png" />
</TabbedPage>
```

I tried Url of the image, using file path located at android project (Resources/drawable) and ImageSource. None of these were able to display the icon.

Comment: Is your tabbed page bottom aligned?

Comment: yes, i think so

Comment: I test the url method that can not show image correctly ,but using file path located and android project(Resources/drawable) could show the image, did you change another Image and make a test? And delete the `obj` and `bin` folder, re-build this project.If it still cannot show, please upload your demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i solved the problem. It was needed to have the image files in each platform. Android on `Resources/drawable` and iOS `Resources`. After that change build action of each image , for Android set `AndroidResource` and iOS `bundleResource`.